# How authenticate web methods in a web service?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'm using Asp.net c# language programming.
What is the best way for authenticating web methods in a web service?
Is it right having authentication for every web method and verify user name and password for each web method?
Is there a way to authenticate just once not for every web method? something like using sessions and etc?

Comment: Web forms or MVC? If webforms, you can put the service in a separate folder and set authentication on that. In MVC, you can do the same, but it requires a bit of magic and trickery.

Comment: @David: his use of the term "web methods" suggests he's talking about an ASMX web service (`[WebMethod]`).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into this one:

http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2006/03/14/implementing-a-secure-token-service-with-wcf.aspx

**Edit**

If you are bound to only use asmx for some reason, then I would also suggest looking into WSE from MSFT.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=018A09FD-3A74-43C5-8EC1-8D789091255D

You can pass around a token from your client into the web method. The token is encrypted with public/private keys.

For more info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996931.aspx

Comment: WCF can fully act as an asmx web service, so might as well since it gives more flexability in the future. So why the cold shoulder?

Comment: How's he going to get authentication if he's limited to basicHttpBinding?

Comment: Then it is becoming a point of consideration to select between pure asmx and wcf isn't it? Which should be a helpful strategy consideration as well...

Comment: I wish I could downvote again, maybe 10 times: don't **ever** suggest WSE. WSE is obsolete and should never be used for anything, unless there are no choices at all. The OP may need to write some code to do authentication, but there's no reason to sentence him to dependence on obsolete software.

Comment: Wow, man, chill. asmx is also can be considered obsolete, so might as well. And what is WSE is being replaced with?

Comment: @dexter: WSE is all but unsupported and has no support in VS2008 or VS2010. All of its functions have been superseded by WCF. ASMX at least still has support in Visual Studio (though you have to hunt for it). I like to use Microsoft's term for ASMX: "legacy technology". Whereas WSE is plain and simple obsolete. I wouldn't suggest the SOAP Toolkit, either, same reason.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be using WCF for web service development unless you're stuck at .NET 2.0.

Secondly, you can use Windows authentication or Basic authentication over https, but those restrict you to users who are Windows users. If you have a separate set of users, then you will need to do your own authentication.

You can use SOAP Headers so that you don't need a username and password in every web method.

Comment: I disagree with the "you should be using WCF for web service development" statement. WCF is overkill for a lot of web service requirements. If you don't need a persistent connection with the service provider, WCF typically isn't necessary.

Comment: He's talking about development of a SOAP web service. What do you suggest he use? Are you aware that Microsoft now considers ASMX to be "legacy technology"? And what's WCF have to do with persistent connections?